# What happens to the temperature and pressure when you open and then close a system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure

A bottle filled with air is moved into a new environment, and reaches thermal equilibrium with the environment, with a temperature $T_{env}$. The bottle now has a presure $p_1$, which is *lower* than the environment's, $p_{env}$. The cap of the bottle is removed and put back after a very short period of time. What then happends to the pressure and the temperature of the bottle? And can we consider the both the state before the cap is removed, and after the cap is put back as closed systems?

Here is my understanding:
The pressure of the bottle instantly equalizes with the environtment, so $p_2=p_{env}$. Because of the sudden change in pressure, the temperature of the bottle changes to $T_2$. Now we put the cap back and I assume $T_2$ has not changed yet. But now the bottle will exchange heat and reach thermal equilibrium. This change in temperature results in  a change of the pressure. 
I am asked to explain this with the First law of Thermodynamics, $\Delta U = Q-W$, but the First law can only be used for *closed* systems, and we quite clearly open our system. Is it because we only consider the two closed states, before and after the cap is moved? But in that case I don't believe the energy should be conserved, because of the interaction with the environment.

*Note*: I have heavily edited this post to better reflect a general situation.

Comment: Is p1 higher or lower than $p_{env}$?  This seems to me to be a problem designed to test your ability to apply the open system (control volume) version of the 1st law of thermodynamics.  The 1 second time interval is obviously meant for you to conclude that the process is adiabatic.  The answer to this problem is going to quantitatively involve the ratio of the heat capacities $\gamma$.

Comment: When another member sends you a comment with a question, it is only courteous for you to respond.

Comment: I have a different perspective on this problem.  If $p_1<p_{env}$, then, when the cap is opened and gas from outside  flows in, the number of mols of gas within the bottle will increase.  If we apply the open system version of the first law of thermodynamics to this situation, we obtain $$n_fu_f-n_iu_i=(n_f-n_i)h_{env}$$where the u's are molar internal energies, the n's are numbers of mols before and after, and $h_{env}$ is molar enthalpy of incoming gas.  For an ideal gas, $n_i=\frac{p_1V}{RT_{env}}$,$n_f=\frac{p_{env}V}{RT_f}$, $u_f=C_vT_f$,$u_i=C_vT_{env}$, and $h_{env}=C_pT_{env}$.  Get Tf

Comment: So, $$\frac{T_f}{T_{env}}=\frac{\gamma}{1+(\gamma-1)\frac{p_1}{p_{env}}}$$

Comment: I apologize for the late respone. I have edited the post to now include $p_1<p_{env}$. I'm quite sure we have not studied the open system version of the first law, but it makes sence none the less. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel I may be being naive, or missing the point of the question, but it seems the paucity of information drives the answer.

My first question is, would you not expect the pressures to equalise? In which case, $p_2$ = $p_{env}$, and your problem resolves to :

$$ \frac{p_1}{T_{env}}= \frac{p_{env}}{T_2}$$

with 3 knowns, 1 unknown (if that's the correct equation to use).

However, if that isn't the case, for example the bottle has a narrow opening and pressure hasn't equalised fully, then you simply wouldn't have enough information to decide what intermediate pressure is reached, when its closed again.  In which case the problem would be self evidently indeterminate anyway - it could have one of many combinations of temp + pressure depending how narrow the opening was etc.

*As that's clearly not intended, the answer can only be that pressure is equalised  and you have 3 knowns, 1 unknown as above.*

## But you need to think a bit more, before being sure the answer is that simple

The reason I've said "if that's the correct equation", is that of course, a change in pressure means a change of volume. Meaning if  $p_1$ > $p_{env}$, the air inside has expanded and some was lost to the environment. If $p_1$ < $p_{env}$, the air inside has compressed, and some air from the external environment has entered the bottle.

You may need to think about how that affects the outcome, but it shouldn't be hard since I think we can safely assume it reaches pressure equilibrium, for reasons given above.

We must also assume (reasonably for homework) that nothing else happens.  For example "air" is not a pure or ideal gas. It contains moisture that can behave very differently from an ideal gas. There could be phase changes (liquid to gas). The air inside and out could be different (its a "different environment").  If it or the outside air are a mix of gasses, each gas has its own partial pressure.

So there are assumptions,you're assuming at minimum, that the "air"/gas in both environments is the same, and behaves ideally in all temperatures and pressures involved. Really they should specify "ideal gas", not air, and that its the same gas in both environments. Air and gas aren't the same thing at all.

Comment: What about the change in the number of moles of gas in the bottle?

Comment: As I said, if the pressure changes, the volume changes and either some air will be lost, or outside air will enter.

Comment: With your answer, I believe I know understand what's going on:
When the cap is removed, the presurre equalizes so p_2 = p_env (as you said). The sudden pressure change leads to an instant temperature change of the bottle, T_env -> T_2. Now, the bottle is sealed, and heat exchange leads to T_2 -> T_env, which in turn changes the pressure.
As for solving the problem above, I believe it's just the "simple" solution, so p_2 = p_env and T_2 = T_env * p2/p1.

Comment: Though I am not sure why a change in pressure neccesarily means a change in volume. The ideal gas law states:
PV = NkT
So if V is constant, a pressure change simply leads to a change in temperature T and the number of particles N.

Comment: Some corrections for you.  The bottle doesn't instantaneously change temp (it takes time), but the air does instantaneously changes temp **because** it expands/compresses.  The ideal gas law in simple terms says that, out of pressure, volume, temperature, and number of particles, if you change one, at least one of the others must also change. If the pressure goes down and the temperature and number of particles stay the same, the volume must have reduced. If the pressure goes down and the temp and volume stay the same, you must have reduced the number of particles in the bottle. And so on....